# Java Hit Formulas

Tags: java

I'm making a simple RPG game and finding out formulas is hard. So far I hav this:

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class expTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int myLevel = 6;
int myAttack = 6;
int myDefense = 1;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
    int rawr = monsterFormula(myLevel, myAttack, myDefense);


 System.out.println("At level " +myLevel+ " you hit for " + df.format(rawr) + " attack points!");

}


public static int monsterFormula(int e,int myAttack, int myDefense) {

 int xTotal = 0;
 for(int i=1; i<e; i++) {
        xTotal += (int)Math.floor(i + myAttack * Math.pow(myDefense, (i / 42.0)));
    }
      return (int)Math.floor(xTotal/8.0);
}


}
```

but...it seems overpowered because at level 10 with attack 10, you hit for 10.
Do you see anyway I can improve my hit formula?

Comment: Improve?  I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about.  What are you trying to do here?   I hate seeing code riddled with magic numbers like this.  It's not a good sign.

Comment: Agree with @duffymo Can you please give us more details. What would be an acceptable hit value per level etc. Why you are not happy with this maybe you are overcomplicating it too much? E.g. level/ 5 and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off this would be better off at game-dev, as this isn't exactly programming related.

But it's okay.

Repeat after me: Game balance is hard, and will take more time than the programming.

Again.

Game balance is hard, and will take more time than the programming.

Okay, now that it's drilled into your head, you do have a couple tools at your disposal.

You have three primary components to what is overpowered.

1. The attacker's ability to scale up outgoing damage.
2. The defender's ability to scale down incoming damage.
3. The amount of damage the defender can take before losing the battle.

One (cheap) way to balance the game is to simply scale up (or down) the players' health. This is surprisingly effective, but loses it's power when you add in healing (because then you have to scale the healing differently.)

Here's how I work out game balance issues. I take some things that I know are constant for me.

1. Someone at level X should win against a level X+2 (assuming equal skill) about 90% of the time.
2. A fight between two level X players should last, on average, 90 seconds.
3. A fight against a dragon/boss should take 3-4 minutes at minimum gear.

And then work backwards to reach the formulas for attack power, damage, and the like.

Comment: Thank you for this informative post. One question: What do oyu mean by scale up (or down) a player's health?

Comment: Well, instead of thinking of damage in terms of how much damage you do "20 points, 30 points" think of it instead in terms of %hp of defender. Say you want the average monster-fight to last about 20 seconds, with a hit every 3 seconds. That's roughly 7 hits, so you should make sure each hit is about 14% of the monster's health. If you find the hits are usually 20%, then you just give the monster more hitpoints. If you find the hits are usually 10% you just give the monster less hit points.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want that formula to give you; it's pretty ad hoc.

Here's how I'd test it out:

```
package cruft;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Monster
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
        int maxLevel = 10;
        for (int level = 1; level <= maxLevel; ++level)
        {
            int maxAttack = 10;
            for (int attack = 1; attack <= maxAttack; ++attack)
            {
                int maxDefense = 10;
                for (int defense = 1; defense <= maxDefense; ++defense)
                {
                    double points = monsterFormula(level, attack, defense);
                    System.out.printf("level: %2d attack: %2d defense: %2d points: %10.3f\n", level, attack, defense, points);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static int monsterFormula(int level, int attack, int defense)
    {

        int xTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < level; i++)
        {
            xTotal += (int) Math.floor(i + attack * Math.pow(defense, (i / 42.0)));
        }
        return (int) Math.floor(xTotal / 8.0);
    }
}
```